# Editing wp-config.php

Tags: plugins, actions, filters, wp-config, pluggable

I need to add the line `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);`

to my config.php , so that post revisions are disabled.

I don't have access to wp-config.php, I have permission to edit my theme and plugins.
Is their any way i could add this code to my theme's function.php, or is their any hook to achieve it.

also,

Is their anyway to override the function which has been defined in wp-config.php
for eg:

```
define( 'BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'profile' );
```

can i override the above line of code without accessing wp-config.php.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the plugin can override it, use action, init with a function to disable it. for example

```
add_action(init,'my_disable_revision');

function my_disable_revision ()
{
 define( 'BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'profile' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin called Revision Control: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revision-control/